# In my Javascript Unit test, expect(true).toBeTruthy() fails

Tags: javascript, karma-runner

I do not understand how this is possible. I got this test from an example and it seems impossible for it to be failing, but it is:

```
expect(true).toBeTruthy();
```

.

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0) Controller:TrivialCtrl should be truthy FAILED
    undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'expect(true).toBeTruthy()')
    c:/Users/Donald/workspace/karma-trivial/spec.js:25:28
```

This is Karma with Chai, Mocha, and PhantomJS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `expect` function is typically used with the `chai` assertion library: have you loaded this plugin?

You need to:

`npm install chai karma-chai --save-dev`

And add `karma-chai` to your list of plugins.

Additionally, reviewing the chai docs, I'm not sure if `toBeTruthy` is an operator: http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/.

You can however use `ok`:

`expect(true).to.be.ok`

Comment: changing it to `to.be.ok` worked. I didn't realize these things were defined in chai. I've been searching for answers from karma. The example that I read didn't specify which assertion library it was using. Can I ask you to please include a link for that documentation in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I replaced

```
expect(match).toBeTruthy();
```

by traditional chai

```
expect(match).not.be.undefined;
```